# How do I add someone to a scheduled Outlook meeting without sending that update to everyone else?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have scheduled a recurring Outlook meeting that everyone has already accepted.  Now I need to include one more person, and I'd like to send her the invitation "officially" so that it appears on her calendar.  But I don't want the attendees who have already accepted the meeting to receive the invitation again and think it's something they need to respond to.

Answer (score 56):

This worked for me in the Outlook versions 2010 & 2016, as well as **Office 365 Mail**

I was able to invite an additional attendee as the organizer of the meeting as follows:

1. Open up the Meeting from your calendar
2. In the *To:* field add in the new attendee  (I'm sure you could add them to the CC field as well)
3. Click on the button *Send Update* (For Office 365 just click on *Send*)
4. A dialog box appears where you have the choice to send to only the added
   attendee(s) or to everybody as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

For **Office 365** the dialog box will look as follows:

[image]

Comment: Was worried the box would not show up after hitting **Send Update** but it did! I am using Outlook Web App. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I also see Office 365 works slightly differently, so I updated the answer.

Comment: Even though the tooltip of the _Send Update_ Button said _Send updated meeting information to **all** attendees_, this very dialog box appeared. (I'm using Outlook for Mac Version 15.23 (Office 2016).)

Comment: Amazing that I had to come to stackoverflow to figure this out. Well done Microsoft ! And btw i just added a few peole and SendUpdate went away without asking giving any of the popups mentioned above !

Answer (score 21):

Rather than editing the event or meeting you can forward it to this new person only.

You can do this from either the calendar view, or from the item view.

In calendar view, select the item and click `Forward` from the ribbon, or right click the item and select `Forward` from the context menu. In item view, select `Forward` from the ribbon. Enter the new person's address and they will be invited to the meeting.

Comment: The above answer only applies if you're an invitee yourself. It doesn't allow you to forward an invite for a meeting you are the organizer of.